# How to make UI's border disappear in Play mode in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

In Game mode, the UI's border does not disappear, I have tried many times to fixed it but it still there.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling gizmos in the game view, but it's not likely to be the case.

Another thing may be any of your UI elements, try disabling and enabling them to see if the border disappears.

Or simply restarting Unity.

Comment: The border still there when I disable the Gizmos

Comment: Have you tried restarting Unity? I had similar problems and solved them by simply restarting

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have checked and unchecked everything...

Comment: I have restarting Unity and it has disappear. Thank for your help.